# Function to read specific rows and columns of a file in a folder

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, readr

I have, for example, 2 *.csv files in a folder.
I would like to create a function that read line by line columns 1 and 3 of each file and save each line as a vector in a list.
To the last, merge these lines by name of the column 1.

The 2 example of files:

```
set.seed(10)
df1 <- tibble(var1 = c("sp1", "sp2", "sp3", "sp4", "sp5", "sp6", "sp7", "sp8", "sp9", "sp10"),
              var2 = round(rnorm(10), 1),
              var3 = round(rnorm(10), 3))
set.seed(11)
df2 <- tibble(var1 = c("sp1", "sp2", "sp3", "sp4", "sp5", "sp6", "sp7", "sp8", "sp9", "sp10"),
              var2 = round(rnorm(10), 1),
              var3 = round(rnorm(10), 3))
```

output expected:

```
   var1  df1$var3 df2$var3
   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 sp1      1.10    -0.828
 2 sp2      0.756   -0.348
 3 sp3     -0.238   -1.54 
 4 sp4      0.987   -0.256
 5 sp5      0.741   -1.15 
 6 sp6      0.089    0.012
 7 sp7     -0.955   -0.223
 8 sp8     -0.195    0.888
 9 sp9      0.926   -0.592
10 sp10     0.483   -0.656
```

Comment: Yes. Drop column var2.
But the intention is read these files in a folder line by line saving them as vectors. Fo the last, merge these lines by a specific column.

Comment: I have hundred of files in a folder with thousand of  lines each file. I trying to create a function that optimize my code.
The best way, that I know, is read and save the lines of these files as vectors in a list, but I do not known to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a join operation. Just read in both files as a data.frame, then drop `var2` and join them on `var1`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- select(df1, -var2)
df2 <- select(df2, -var2)

full_join(df1, df2, by = 'var1', suffix = c('.df1', '.df2'))
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   var1  var3.df1 var3.df2
   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 sp1      1.10    -0.828
 2 sp2      0.756   -0.348
 3 sp3     -0.238   -1.54 
 4 sp4      0.987   -0.256
 5 sp5      0.741   -1.15 
 6 sp6      0.089    0.012
 7 sp7     -0.955   -0.223
 8 sp8     -0.195    0.888
 9 sp9      0.926   -0.592
10 sp10     0.483   -0.656
```

Your choice of join type depends on what you want to do if the 2 tables don't have the exact same selection of values in `var1`